# What does the word "brembedell" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I heard this word in a song by Nicki Minaj and Britney Spears. This line:

> "Anyway, brembedell, whats that?
>
> I don’t know: Femme Fatale."

What does the word "brembedell" mean?

Comment: According to the song it seems to mean *femme fatale* . . .

Answer (score 3):

It’s a made-up word; it makes little sense; apparently, it’s used as a rhyme for something. Nicki Minaj raps this part, and such meaningless words may help to control the flow.